# Filter DataTable Plugin JS

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, plugins, datatables

I need to know how to make my search filter that is with the JS Datatable plugin do a search with the exact value, now when placing the value 1 for example, it returns the numbers 1, 21, 113, 41 etc. It is a simple code only I can not find how to do that ...

I hope you can help

```
 $('#txtFolioFilter').on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            table
                .columns(13)
                **.search = ( this.value )**
                .draw();
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom search function. The following example assumes you are using the standard DataTables global search field - which can be selected using the following jQuery selector:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input')
```

Here is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    // your table initialization here
  } );

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
        var searchTerm = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
        if (searchTerm.trim() === "") {
          return true;
        }
        var exactMatch = false;
        searchData.forEach(function (cellText) {
          if (searchTerm === cellText) {
            exactMatch = true;
          }
        });
        return exactMatch;
    }
  );

} );
```

The following line captures all search events from the main search box:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(...)
```

A blank search term will return all records.

Otherwise, for each row, we check each field in the row, and return that row as matched if any of the fields exactly match the search term.

If you want to apply this "exact match" to only one column, then you can adjust the custom filter:

```
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
        var searchTerm = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
        if (searchTerm.trim() === "") {
          return true;
        }
        var match = false;
        searchData.forEach(function (cellText, index) {
          if (index === 3) {
            if (searchTerm === cellText) {
              match = true;
            }
          } else {
            // all other columns:
            if (cellText.includes(searchTerm)) {
              match = true;
            }
          }
        });
        return match;
    }
  );
```

With this approach, what rows are displayed will depend on what your data looks like across the entire row, of course.
Documentation for the search plug-in is [here](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search), for more background.